# kivy undefined symbols text_input

Tags: android, kivy, textinput, undefined-symbol

In my app I make use of TextInput in the .kv file. When I run the app on Android on my HTC One X+ (Cyanogenmod OS 10) and I press the TextInput field to type my Keyboard appears, but also it automatically adds this symbol: □　(symbol for encoding doesn't support the character).　So pressing TextInput automatically inserts □ as text. The strange thing is that this doesn't happen on my PC and also not when using the Kivy Launcher on my phone. It only happens when I use Buildozer to package the app and run it on my phone.

```
TextInput:
    id: txt_field
    text: "What you type here"
    font_size: '20sp'
    multiline: False
    size_hint_x: .8
```

Did someone else also got this problem? I could make an input filter, but I'm curious to why this happens.

Comment: Could you try building with kivy master (if you aren't already)? there have been several recent fixes related to this. The launcher version may predate both the problem and the fixes.

Comment: I just upgraded to the Master Branch (Kivy v.1.8.1-dev is Master right?), but the same problem is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been solved in the stable and the master versions you just need to clean your existing builds and the package cache. Run the following command. From your app dir.

```
bulldozer android clean
rm -rf ~/.buildozer/android/packages
rm -rf ~/.buildozer/android/cache
```

Then just rebuild your apk.